# Changing the color of user defined commands in TeXmaker

Tags: highlighting, texmaker

I have some own commands (as \note) that I usually define in the beginning of each document, which I would like TeXmaker to highlight in the same way as similar commands such as sections and math are given own and distinct colors in the the .tex document when viewed in TeXmaker (i.e. I would like to be able to give my own commands colors distinct from those of other commands). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- user tags like `\begin{customenvironment}....
     \end{customenvironment}` can be added using Texmaker menu --> User-->User tags-->Edit User tags
- user latex commands like `\note[]{}` can be added using 
  Texmaker menu--> User--> Customize completion. In Customize completion dialog box type `\note[@]{@}` --> Press add-->Ok ( `@` brings a vacant `.` to replace with command options)

Sometimes it may need a restart of Texmaker for user tags.

For more texmaker documentation go through this

http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION33

Comment: Yes, but how do I change the color of my own commands?

Comment: @malin personally i dont change color code, i like the defaults. try configure-->Editor-->colors

Comment: Its not possible to set the color of any specific commands there...  :-(

Comment: @malin you are right. only for user commands there is no option to change color