# \newenvironment does not work

Tags: environments, align, subequations

I have created a new environment using this commands:

```
\newenvironment{eqs}
    {\begin{subequations}\begin{align}}
    {\end{align}\end{subequations}
    }
```

I would like to combine subequations and align environment together, 
but it just does not work. Any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: That because `align` simply cannot be used like that. I'm not sure it would be worth creating such an env in the first place.

Comment: using `\newenvironment{eqns}{\subequations\align}{\endalign\endsubequations}` works...

Comment: cmhughes: Thanks a lot . yeah it works now.
Do you have any idea why the command in this environment is not green , as it should be when I use a single align (or equation) environment? is there any way to fix it?

Comment: when you say 'green', are you describing syntax highlighting? if so, I probably won't be able to answer, but for anyone else, which editor are you using?

Comment: @Amir The syntax coloring depends on what editor you're using and it's impossible to say anything without knowing what it is. About this `eqs` environment: you're losing the possibility of defining a global label for the subequations.

Comment: I use texmaker and this editor shows any math environment in green.
Is there any method we can make this new environment a global one so that we can have it green like other built-in environment?

Comment: @cmhughes An answer? Ping me when you do.

Comment: @egreg probably better from you, I'll vote for it :)

Answer (score 3):

For TeXnical reasons, the syntax you're proposing can't work with `\begin` in the “start” part and `\end` in the “finish” part. This is due to the fact that `align` collects the environment's content as a whole before starting the typesetting; the reason is that it has to do some measurements and so it has to process the content multiple times.

The collecting works by fetching whatever comes up to the closing `\end{...}`, where `...` is the name of the environment the alignment was started with. Here's the problem: when you have

```
\newenvironment{eqs}
  {\begin{subequations}\begin{align}}
  {\end{align}\end{subequations}}
```

and do `\begin{eqs}`, the alignment starts at `\begin{align}`, but no `\end{align}` is seen because it's hidden in `\end{eqs}`, whereas `\end{align}` should be explicitly in the input.

The solution is simple: use the “internal” macros used by `align` and `subequations`:

```
\newenvironment{eqs}
  {\subequations\align}
  {\endalign\endsubequations}
```

In this way `\align` starts the alignment, but the opening environment's name is `eqs` (because no other `\begin` command has been executed), so `amsmath` knows it has to find `\end{eqs}` for terminating the alignment, whereupon it will execute the “finish” part.

As far as I know, it's not possible to change coloring of user defined environments in Texmaker, see [Changing the color of user defined commands in TeXmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84769/changing-the-color-of-user-defined-commands-in-texmaker) with answer and comments. See also [Environment definition gives an error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151562/environment-definition-gives-an-error) for a similar problem.