# A problem with environment starting macro

Tags: macros, environments

For some reason I want a macro `\BeginControl` such that `\BeginControl{\environment}` is equivalent to `\begin{environment}`. I have put together some code. It usually works but there is a problem with starred environments I'm trying to solve.

Consider the following code. The two instances of `align*` environment should behave the same, but it yields a wrong looking error `! LaTeX Error: \begin{align*} on input line 33 ended by \end{align*}.` Where is the problem?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\cdef}{\newcommand*}

\cdef \Expanded [1]{%
    \begingroup
    \edef \x {%
        \endgroup
        #1%
    }%
    \x
}
\cdef \Apply [1]{%
    \Expanded{\noexpand #1}%
}
\cdef \IgnoreNext [1]{%
    % ignore next token
}
\cdef \MacroName [1]{%
    \expandafter\IgnoreNext \string#1%
}
\cdef \BeginControl [1]{%
    \Apply{\begin{\MacroName{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        A \\
        B
    \end{align*}
    \BeginControl{\align*}
        A \\
        B
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**Update**: Thanks to the answers I found out that my macro `\MacroName` is incorrect since it expands to the macro name with catcode 12 instead of 11 due to `\string`. The following definition should work:

```
\let \Ex \expandafter
\cdef \ExEx {%
    \Ex\Ex\Ex
}
\cdef \ExExArg [2]{%
    \ExEx#1\ExEx{#2}%
}
\cdef \MacroName [1]{%
    \ExExArg\scantokens{\Ex\IgnoreNext \string#1\noexpand}%
}
```

Comment: Also `\BeginControl{\align}` would produce the same error.

Comment: @egreg: I see, I was blaming the star, but it seems to be some ugly implementation detail of `\align`. The macros work ok for theorems and itemize. If I remember I had also similar problem with frame environment in beamer.

Comment: No, it doesn't work with `itemize` either. What's the purpose of having `\BeginControl{\foo}` instead of `\begin{foo}`?

Comment: @egreg: Interesting, I use it in conjuction with `\cdef \EndCurrent {\Apply{\end{\@currenvir}}}`. But with theorems and itemize, it seemed to work with no problem.

Comment: `align` is special: it needs to see `\end{align}` explicitly, not buried in a macro. See, for instance, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196238/newenvironment-does-not-work

Comment: Now I see what you're trying. Don't: you're giving up error checking. For `amsmath` environment you're doomed, unless you redefine them all to look for `\EndCurrent` instead of `\end{<environment>}`.

Comment: @egreg That's unfortunate. I really don't like the fact that changing from displayed math to align or chaning environments involves more changes than just changing the name of the used environment at one place. I should really find some time to write a preprocessor that would generate Latex code. Note that I wouldn't give up error checking when the environment block would be determined by indentation of source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see what happens with

```
\BeginControl{\align}
```

Step 1: expand `\BeginControl`

```
\Apply{\begin{\MacroName{\align}}}
```

Step 2: expand `\Apply`

```
\Expanded{\noexpand\begin{\MacroName{\align}}}
```

Step 3: expand `\Expanded`

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\begin{\MacroName{\align}}}\x
```

Step 4: `\begingroup` is executed; open a group and remove the command.

Step 5: `\edef` causes full expansion of the given *balanced text*.

Substep 5.1: `\endgroup` is unexpandable, push it in the token list to be built.

Substep 5.2: `\noexpand` makes the next token unexpandable; remove it and push `\begin` to the token list being built.

Substep 5.3: `{` is unexpandable, push it.

Substep 5.4: expand `\MacroName`

```
\expandafter\IgnoreNext\string\align
```

Substep 5.5: `\expandafter` expands `\string` and is removed. Note that `\string\align` produces `\align` as characters *all having category code* 12.

Substep 5.6: expand `\IgnoreNext`; the backslash is removed.

Substeps 5.7-5.11: the tokens `align` are unexpandable; push them to the token list being built.

Substep 5.12: `}` is unexpandable, push it

Step 6: the token list is `\endgroup\begin{align}`; TeX executes `\def\x{\endgroup\begin{align}}`

Step 7: expand `\x`, which replaces `\x` with the token list above.

Step 8: `\endgroup` closes the opened group, the meaning of `\x` is forgotten.

Step 9: `\begin{align}` is executed.

It seems it ought to work; alas, no.

Remember that `align` is a string of characters having category code 12; when LaTeX executes `\begin{align}` it sets `\@currenvir` to `align` (all category codes 12); the execution of `\end{align}` compares the argument to `\@currenvir` and they turn out to be different, because in `\end{align}` the characters have category code 11.

You can check that

```
\expandafter\begin\expandafter{\string minipage}{25pt}
xyz
\end{minipage}
```

gives the same error: only `m` has category code 12, but this is sufficient for the two “strings” at `\begin` and `\end` to be different.

The error has been explained; I'm not sure what your aim is with such a complicated approach.

---

A solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\BeginControl}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\begin{\scantokens\expandafter{\x\noexpand}}}%
  \x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\BeginControl{\enumerate}
\item xyz
\end{enumerate}

\BeginControl{\align}
  A \\
  B
\end{align}

\BeginControl{\align*}
  A \\
  B
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The `\scantokens` rereads the string with the usual category codes.

Comment: The error message could have been designed better in the case the characters match but not their catcodes. Is there something like `\show` that shows also the catcodes?

Comment: @user87690 -- you can use `\the` before `\catcode` to retrieve the current catcode.

Comment: @Ruben: What if you want catcodes of all tokens in a defined macro? I mean – is there any standard tool for such debuging?

Comment: @user87690 See `\showcat` macro here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228979/

Comment: @user87690 As far as TeX is concerned, `a` with category code 12 is different from `a` with category code 11. So LaTeX tells you that the environment was started with a different name than it ended; the fact that the shown string seem equal is incidental.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that LaTeX checks the equivalence of strigs+catcodes in its `\@endcheck`, because `\ifx` is used. Normal typed environment has letters with catcodes 11 and others characters in 12 but the string generated by `\string` has letters in catcode 12.

You must to re-catcode the string to catcodes 11. I suggest a similar expanable macro for this based on `\ifcase`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\recatcode#1{\ifx#1\relax\else
  \ifcase\numexpr`#1-`A\relax A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\or G\or H\or I\or
      J\or K\or L\or M\or N\or O\or P\or Q\or R\or S\or T\or U\or V\or W\or
      X\or Y\or Z\or#1\or#1\or#1\or#1\or#1\or#1\or
      a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or
      j\or k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or s\or t\or u\or v\or w\or 
      x\or y\or z\else #1\fi
  \expandafter\recatcode\fi
}
\def\BeginControl#1{\edef\x{\expandafter\ignoreone\string#1}%
  \edef\x{\expandafter\recatcode\x\relax}%
  \expandafter\begin\expandafter{\x}%
}
\def\ignoreone#1{}

\begin{document}  
    \begin{align*}
        A \\
        B
    \end{align*}

    \BeginControl{\align}
        A \\
        B
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice alternative to `\scantokens` for non e-TeX.